# SAML - Service Provider could not handle the request

Tags: saml-2.0, picketlink

I am self learning SAML. I am learning using picket link quick starts: https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-picketlink-quickstarts.

I deployed picketlink-federation-saml-idp-basic-wildfly.war in wildfly 9.0.2 running in port 9080 and picketlink-federation-saml-sp-post-basic-wildfly.war deployed in wildfly 9.0.2 running in port 8080. I also updated standalone.xml to update security domain for IDP and SP.

The only change I had todo in sample, was to update dependency of picketlink-jbas7, since the version in sample 2.8.0.Beta1-SNAPSHOT cannot to resolved. The maven dependency I am using in IDP is:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.picketlink.distribution</groupId>
        <artifactId>picketlink-jbas7</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The issue I am facing is, when I login to IDP and click on the SP link I get following exception in SP logs:

```
23:05:55,833 ERROR [org.picketlink.common] (default task-5) Service Provider could not handle the request.: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.handlers.saml2.SAML2IssuerTrustHandler$SPTrustHandler.handleStatusResponseType(SAML2IssuerTrustHandler.java:143)
at org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.handlers.saml2.SAML2IssuerTrustHandler.handleStatusResponseType(SAML2IssuerTrustHandler.java:70)
at org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.process.SAMLHandlerChainProcessor.callHandlerChain(SAMLHandlerChainProcessor.java:67)
at org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.process.ServiceProviderSAMLResponseProcessor.processHandlersChain(ServiceProviderSAMLResponseProcessor.java:106)
at org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.process.ServiceProviderSAMLResponseProcessor.process(ServiceProviderSAMLResponseProcessor.java:88)
at org.picketlink.identity.federation.bindings.wildfly.sp.SPFormAuthenticationMechanism.handleSAML2Response(SPFormAuthenticationMechanism.java:516)
at org.picketlink.identity.federation.bindings.wildfly.sp.SPFormAuthenticationMechanism.handleSAMLResponse(SPFormAuthenticationMechanism.java:306)
at org.picketlink.identity.federation.bindings.wildfly.sp.SPFormAuthenticationMechanism.authenticate(SPFormAuthenticationMechanism.java:268)
at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.transition(SecurityContextImpl.java:339)
at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.transition(SecurityContextImpl.java:356)
at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl$AuthAttempter.access$100(SecurityContextImpl.java:325)
at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.attemptAuthentication(SecurityContextImpl.java:138)
at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authTransition(SecurityContextImpl.java:113)
at io.undertow.security.impl.SecurityContextImpl.authenticate(SecurityContextImpl.java:106)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:55)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue learning from picketbox quickstarts. I am working with wildfly 10.1.0.Final.

The first thing I noticed was that in order to get the "**Basic**" working is necessary (https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-picketlink-quickstarts):

- IDP: *picketlink-federation-saml-idp-basic*
- SP(s): *picketlink-federation-saml-sp-post-basic* and *picketlink-federation-saml-sp-redirect-basic*

I deployed all generated .war in one container for simplicity.

There were **two things that helped me** find what was going on:

- enable TRACE debug
- version of picketlink is **2.5.5.SP2 in Wildfly 10** and *SAML2LoginModule* was not found in that package in **picketlink-wildfly8-2.5.5.SP2.jar**.

In particular I had a problem with login module getting this error:

```
Class org.picketlink.identity.federation.bindings.wildfly.SAML2LoginModule not found from Module "deployment.picketlink-federation-saml-sp-post-basic-wildfly.war:main" from Service Module Loader

Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule class: org.picketlink.identity.federation.bindings.wildfly.SAML2LoginModule
```

What I did was change login module to: **org.picketlink.identity.federation.bindings.jboss.auth.SAML2LoginModule** and the quickstart started working.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on picketlink.

I used openSAML, and I was able to develop IDP initiated and SP initiated flows with no issues.

References: 
https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/OSTwoUserManual#
https://github.com/rasmusson/webprofile-ref-project